# How can I make a jQuery plugin and call it recursively?

Tags: jquery, plugins

How can I call a jQuery plugin recursively?
I have a file named `poll.js` inside of a main.php. I made a plugin named `poll` calling `order_provider.php` to catch new order of logged in shop. `poll` function should check every 15sec if a new order registered. I need to call `poll` recursively.
I made the plugin something like this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.poll = function (shopid){
           $.getJSON("order_provider.php?looking=all&shopid="+shopid, function(data){
              // Do Something
           }).done(function(){
              // Do Something
              setTimeout(poll(shopid),15000)
           })
    }
 })(jQuery);
```

But it doesn't work except once!

Answer (score 0):

that it is because `setTimeout` only works once, try `setInterval` instead.
here it is the [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window#Methods)

so i think it should look something like this, i havent tested.. but maybe can give you a start or idea in how to make work

```
//the shop id it is to check if the users is login...
// this ajax call is used for gettings new items for that client
//set the php value for a hidden field
$(document).ready(function(){

/*
    (function($) {
        var shopid = document.getElementById("userid").value;
        $.fn.poll = function(shopid) {
            $.getJSON("order_provider.php?looking=all&shopid=" + shopid, function(data) {}).done(function() {
                var shopinterval = setInterval(function(shopid) {
                    $(this).poll(shopid);
                }, 15E3);
            }).fail(function(shopid) {
                errorhandler(shopid);
            });
        }
        $.fn.errorhandler = function(shopid) {
            clearInterval(shopinterval);
            //try again
            console.log("error");
            poll(shopid);
        }
    })(jQuery);
*/
    var shopid = document.getElementById("userid").value;

    if(shopid != null || shopid != null || shopid != undefined){
        setInterval(function(shopid){
            poll(shopid);
        }, 15E3);
    }  

    function poll(userId){  
        $.getJSON("order_provider.php?looking=all&shopid=" + shopid, function(data) {}).done(function() {
            var shopinterval = setInterval(function(shopid) {
                $(this).poll(shopid);
            }, 15E3);
        }).fail(function(shopid) {
            errorhandler(shopid);
        });
    }

    function errorHandler(userId){
        var confirmation=confirm("Press a button");
        if (confirmation==true){
            clearInterval(shopinterval);
            poll(shopid);
          }else{
             console.log("error");
          }         

    }

});
```

**Note** Im not really sure if it is did what you mean, but give it a try, also this is based since the php code it is outputting the user id, so instead of making the call from php to the javascript(bad practice), it expect to be a `input` field, hidden with the value that we need... i hope it can help you more..
ps.. i just did it in the train, so i dont know if it will work out of the box... ;)

Comment: I used your code and test it but I found no way to call poll function.
this code cause an error-> ReferenceError: poll in not defined!

Comment: @Saeid My bad, looks like `$.getJSON` works with `fail` to handle erros

Comment: I found we should call poll inside setInterval func as $(this).poll(shopid) but shopid send as undifined! :(

Comment: @Saeid that it is because it has been used already, i think it is better to `setInterval` in the same `while` that it is sending the call for the ajax.. make sense?

Comment: I think I don't get your mean but If I got, I should call poll function when the ajax complete not while!

Comment: so you want to call the same `shopid` over and over again?

Comment: yes, cause I use this poll on the shop that logged in!
Each shop logging in and send its id to server and catch it's orders!

Comment: so it is a static value why dont you set a if to check if it is undefined, and if it is set its value to the right one

Comment: But how can I find the value of `shopid` inside that if?

Comment: I dont follow your logic.. can you explain fast in the question how it is your class or method structure and which values are pass around the methods.. cause i dont follow you right now :(

Comment: where is `shopid` coming from?

Comment: When we call `poll` first time. It come from php code I used to check if the shop logged in!

Comment: and as i understand it, it is now always the same value... so if i was you i would set the setinterval there instead each time i set the userid. because if you do it inside the ajax call, it wont know what shopid **note** comes from php? so you have a API? or just a echo

Comment: I send the request for Orders by ajax and when the new orders come from server I handle them. But i should send another ajax request 15 seconds after I get the previous request successfully done.{I just want to echo and handle data received}

Comment: Im going to sleep now, email me with all this details.. and i will look at it tomorrow morning in case you havent figure it out yet.. my email is my user name @gmail.com

Comment: I use `setInterval` inside of ajax instead of `done` but unfortunately  didn't work. Ok my friend. sleep tight. I will send you an email as soon as possible.

Comment: @Saeid try the new update, it may need some small changes, im not sure how it is your php, so give it a try ;) fun coding

Comment: I could sent `shopid` to `poll` function by declaring a global variable at the top of `getJSON`. (I edit your code). When I test, it work but `setInterval` doesn't call `poll` every 15sec. It call `poll` erratic.

Comment: Wow. I think I sent you previous comment synchronously ;).

Comment: You didn't indicate what should we do if the value of `shopid` was `null` or `undefined`? In addition I think declaring a global variable is more easy to implement instead of using Hidden input or something like that.

Comment: yes it is, but you need to grab the value in javascript of the user id.... and a hidden input is the best solution in my opinion..

Comment: well that it is up to you to implement the `else` ;)

Comment: Check your mail please ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with the implementation

1. setTimeout needs a function references as the argument

A working version could be something like

```
(function ($) {


    $.fn.poll = function (shopid) {
        function poll() {
            $.getJSON("order_provider.php?looking=all&shopid=" + shopid, function (data) {
                // Do Something
            }).done(function () {
                // Do Something
                setTimeout(poll, 15000)
            })
        }

        poll();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

<sub>Note: not looking to make it like a complete plugin... just fixing some issues in the existing version</sub>

Comment: I tried this code but didn't work,
and I don't know where the "shopid" went?!
I need to call "poll" on "shopid" every 15sec!